# Creating a new column for 'week ending date' based on existing date column (MYSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, mysqli

I have a table with a date column but would like to add a another column that shows the week ending date for each day in the table so that I can aggregate values by week ending. I would like to have the week end on a Thursday and the data begins 2017-01-01.

Answer (score 0):

This would be where something like virtual/computed columns would come in to play. There isn't such a thing in PostgreSQL yet however.

One way around it is to use functions and function-based indexes. An example is here: http://bernardoamc.github.io/sql/2015/05/11/postgres-virtual-columns/